# Does GC.GetTotalMemory(false) synchronize threads

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection

When i use `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)` in a multithreaded appliation, does it synchronize all threads during the call?

Maybe some one has the answer? As far as i know, `GC.Collect()` has this behaviour.

**EDIT**

I want to use the method to get to know, how much memory is currently used by the application. The method gets called in different thread, which will be canceled if some memory limit is reached.

Thank you!

Comment: I care because i call the method in different threads to get to know, how much memory the application is currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This doesn't make much difference.

The result will be the same from any of the running threads, because it's reporting on a resource shared by all threads, and the GC generally does enough synchronisation to ensure this works (e.g. two threads simultaneously needing more heap memory won't throw it into an invalid state). Finding the amount of memory thought to be allocated doesn't require locking up all the threads, though it *might* require locking on some other GC operations.

Of course a thread obtaining a large chunk of memory could invalidate the answer you receive by the time you get it, but if all threads were locked this would still be the case, as it would still obtain that large chunk after the lock was released.